# Excel IF statement to find specific actions against a record

Tags: loops, if-statement, excel-formula

The Excel consists of two columns 'Person Number' and 'Action Code'. There can be multiple occurrences of a 'Person Number' for first occurrence the 'Action Code' needs to be 'HIRE' rest occurrences needs to be 'ASG_CHANGE'.

[image: Brief Summary Image]

Used below code to get the 'Expected Action Code' but got 'Invalid Code Output' instead.

=IF($A2:$A3=$A3,"HIRE","ASG_CHANGE")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test whether the value changed:

```
=IF(A1<>A2,"HIRE","ASG_CHANGE")
```